# What is the name of the audio clip used at the start and end of a podcast?

Tags: technical, technology

The bit of a podcast at the beginning and usually the very end too with the branding/title+description+jingle that is always the same? Probably the same word describes what is used for the branding of broadcast audio (uh, radio) too. Bookends? Lead-in/outs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The usual terms I hear are "intro" and "outro". "Intro" is of course short for "introduction", while "outro" is formed by analogy with "intro".

Comment: This is perfect, and what a delightful pair of terms. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that "lead in" / "lead out" as mentioned in your question are probably the most applicable. As Greg suggests, "intro" and "outro" also work, but it's conceivable that you might have a unique intro for a given episode which would be played after the "lead in".

You may even shorten this to simply "lead" for the beginning, and more explicitly use "lead out" when referring to the end.

Just my two cents, but maybe someone in radio or podcasting will offer up an industry accepted alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the end segment is called a [**"sign-off"**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign-off).

Not sure about the beginning segment. Oh, apparently it's called a [**"sign-on"**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign-on). Makes sense!

Note that these technically refer to the *entire* beginning and ending sequences of programs. That includes test patterns and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the term **bumper**:

> In broadcasting, a commercial bumper, ident bumper or break-bumper is a brief announcement, usually two to 15 seconds in length that can contain a voice over, placed between a pause in the program and its commercial break, and vice versa. The host, the program announcer or a continuity announcer states the title (if any) of the presentation, the name of the program, and the broadcast or cable network, though not necessarily in that order. *[...]* Bumper music, often a recurring signature or theme music segment, is nearly always featured.
>   - **[Bumper (broadcasting)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumper_%28broadcasting%29)** from Wikipedia.

As commercials are less common in podcasts, it could certainly be used for the start and end of the broadcast, and it would probably be reused if the recording ever was played in full on a commercial radio station.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that, although "bumper" has a perfectly clear definition (something played before and/or after a commercial break) and that this perfectly clear definition perfectly clearly does not apply in the situation being described (podcasts tend not to have ad breaks and, anyway, the question is about the start and end of the show, not interruptions within it), you think that "bumper" is the right word to use?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks for the downvote. Bumpers do not require adverts, the same segments played at the start and end of radio shows without adverts (such as [BBC Radio 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC_Radio_4)) programmes are also called bumpers. And some podcasts do have adverts, such as Penn's Sunday School.

Comment: Then please quote a definition of the term "bumper" that includes start/end sequences and, therefore, makes your answer relevant to the question. Also, please note that your implicit criticism of what you assume to be my downvote is way off-base. Voting on answers, based on whether one believes them to be correct is a fundamental part of how this site works.